# Is it possible in PostgreSQL to do one query to get the result of object inside object?

Tags: sql, postgresql

At this moment I do query like this :

```
static async getAllAppointmentSerivce () {
    // Get all appointment with detail
    const query = {
      name: 'getAllAppointment',
      text: 'SELECT app.id, cus.name as name, cus.email as email, app.date, app.status, app.link FROM appointments app INNER JOIN admins adm ON app.admin_id = adm.id INNER JOIN customers cus ON app.customer_id = cus.id ORDER BY id ASC'
    }

    return pool.query(query)
      .then(async res => {
        for (let i = 0; i < res.rows.length; i++) {
          const admin = await AdminService.getAdminDetailByAppointmentId(res.rows[i].id)
          res.rows[i].admin = admin
        }
        return res.rows
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err.stack))
  }
```

And the result is like this :
[Query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHUDV.png)

My question is, is that possible to do that in a single query?

Comment: That sounds like the solution would be a join.

Comment: [Images](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/90527) should not be used for textual data.

Comment: Since SQL includes data definition, a [mcve] for an [SQL question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/90527) should include [DDL](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) statements for sample tables (rather than an ad hoc table specification) and [DML](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language) statements for sample data (rather than a dump or ad hoc format). Desired results don't need to be presented as sample code, as results are the output of code and not code themselves.

Comment: The sample only a single query. Does `AdminService .getAdminDetailByAppointmentId` also query the DB? If so, please edit the code sample to create an [mcve]. If an SQL-only solution is desired, the JS can be left out as it's irrelevant (though the relationship between queries would need to be described).